# Angular2 MatTable data with inner array

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table, angular-material

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so I hope I make myself clear.

I'm trying to create a table with dynamic columns, but I fail to understand how should I bind matColumnDef to a specific element position from an array. Since my original code is much more complex and hard to follow, I'll post a simpler version that contains the problem itself.

So here is the HTML code. I should create a column for every element from the inner-array (numere) in "date", (in this case, there are 2, but in my original app the array is dynamic, sometimes it has 2 elements, sometimes it has 4, etc.)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

<div *ngFor="let number of date;let i=index;">
 <ng-container matColumnDef="{{i}}">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.numere[i]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
</div>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

And here is the typescript code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  numere: Array<string>;
}



/**
 * @title Table with filtering
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-filtering-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
})
export class TableFilteringExample {
  date: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H', numere: ["alb","negru"]},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He',numere: ["alb","negru"]},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li',numere: ["galben","roz"]},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be',numere: ["alb","negru"]},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B',numere: ["galben","roz"]},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C',numere: ["alb","negru"]},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N',numere: ["maro","roz"]},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O',numere: ["pink","bombon roz"]},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F',numere: ["alb","negru"]},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne',numere: ["alb","negru"]},
];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol','0','1'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.date);

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Now.. I figured out a way to assign elements to columns, by giving them indexes as 0,1,2,..., array.length, and I can display them in the actual table, but...

The problem is that if I want to add a filter on the table or a mat-sort-header on those columns, it won't work. The sort, for example, needs to have the 'property-name' same as matColumnDef (i.e.: element.*position* <=> matColumnDef='*position*'). But in this case, I don't have a property-name for each element in array (something like 'numere[0]','numere[1]', etc.), only the array property-name itself which is too general to apply it to all the columns and doesn't work.

So if I want to sort the table with respect to the first element in table ('numere[0]') I won't be able, because there is no suck property-name as numere[x].

Any ideas how could I achieve this? Also, I would like to stick with Angular Material library and not change to other options because I was said to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would process the array and flatten it so that there is no nested array inside a array. If I could get away without hacking, I will.

As for sort, Material has its own sort module, don't forget to import it into your module. Otherwise Angualar will ignore directives like `matSort` `mat-sort-header` without any error messages. I used to wonder why my sort didn't work and I found that I forgot to import `MatSortModule`.

Material doc website if off-line at the time of this post, from memory, I think in order to get sort working:

1. import `MatSortModule`
2. add `matSort` to `mat-table` or `table` element
3. add `mat-sort-header` to `mat-header-cell` where you want to enable sort
4. get matSort in component class with @ViewChild
5. assign the above to data source in life cycle hook `ngAfterViewInit`

I hope the above helps.

Comment: The point is that I can't change the variables in the object. I receive from back-end an array of objects as:
{
  "userId": "-45",
  "mail": "alex@whatever.com"
  "username": "alex",
  "state": "1",
  "userChoices": []
}
And I got in my table a column for name, for mail, for state, and columns for every choice of the user (cause one choice belongs to one question and a question has its column).

Comment: I got sort and filter on table, it works perfectly on the first columns, except those from question. It does nothing on them, it doesn't see them and  the problem is on _columnId_ for sure, cause there must be a field name like `firstchoice` and bind the column on it.

Comment: After you receive the data from the backend, you can copy and flattern it to a new array, and then set the data sources’s data property to the flattened array.  If you are having difficulties doing that and require help, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no any solution mentioned. I'll try with mine.
So i had to display actors, directors and genres that are initialy maxSelectedItems="3"

```
actors: (2) [{…}, {…}] , 
directors: [{…}] , 
genres: (2) [{…}, {…}] 

<ng-container matColumnDef="actors">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Actors </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.actors[0].name}} {{row.actors[1] !== undefined ? row.actors[1].name : ''}} {{ row.actors[2] !== undefined ? row.actors[2].name : ''}}</td>
</ng-container>
```